# how to get list of users from OWNERS or designer group for all the site collections in a farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection, groups, farm

Is there a PowerShell way that can give me list of owners for all the site collection and sub-sites from all the web applications in a given farm?

how to get list of users from OWNERS or designer group for all the site collections in a farm?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following powershell to get all site collection owners for each site collection in SharePoint farm:**(Change the file location for yourself)**

```
#Set file location for saving information. We'll create a tab separated file. 
$FileLocation = "C:\Temp\SiteCollectionOwnersReport.csv"
 
#Load SharePoint snap-in 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
 
#Fetches webapplications in the farm 
$WebApplications = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration 
Write-Output "URL `t ID `t Site Collection Owner `t Site Collection Owner Email `t Site Collection Secondary Owner `t Site Collection Secondary Owner Email " | Out-file $FileLocation 
 
foreach($WebApplication in $WebApplications){ 
    #Fetches site collections list within sharepoint webapplication 
    Write-Output "" 
    Write-Output "Working on web application $($WebApplication.Url)" 
    $Sites = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebApplication -Limit All     
 
    foreach($Site in $Sites){      
            #Fetches information for each  site 
            Write-Output "$($Site.Url) `t $($Site.ID.Guid) `t $($Site.Owner.Name) `t $($Site.Owner.Email) `t $($Site.SecondaryContact.Name) `t $($Site.SecondaryContact.Email)" | Out-File $FileLocation -Append 
            $Site.Dispose() 
    } 
} 
 
#Unload SharePoint snap-in 
Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
 
Write-Output "" 
Write-Output "Script Execution finished"
```

Another article about all users in groups in a SharePoint farm.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-all-users-in-a-sharepoint-20101316-farm-using-powershell-script

Reference:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-collection-owners-for-13336f43